# Raspbian (retropie image) doesn't detect my TV

Tags: hdmi, screen, retropie

I have some 40" Samsung smart TV and my Raspberry Pi is connected through HDMI to the TV.

The screen is showing, but when I open the "monitor settings" in the Raspbian GUI it says "The following monitor is detected: ". Yes, it's empty! and the resolution is at 1824x984. I can't change anything.

Anyway, that isn't the problem. I can live with it, but when I start the emulationstation and want to play some games the screen is too big. It's going out of the screen at the top and I don't see the whole picture.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Sound like an [overscan](http://elinux.org/RPi_raspi-config#overscan_-_Change_overscan) issue

Answer (score 2):

Entering `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s` at the command prompt will show the PI's current mode.

`/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT` or `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA` should show what modes the TV supports.

settings can be configured in `/boot/config.txt` if you want to change any.

Look at http://elinux.org/R-Pi_ConfigurationFile which describes the settings in /boot/config.txt.